# Can I set up socket.io chat on heroku?

Tags: sockets, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have a simple socket.io chat application which I've uploaded to one of the new [Heroku 'cedar'](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) stacks.

Now I almost have everything working but I've hit one stumbling block. On my localhost, I open a connection to the socket server from the client with:

```
// lots of HTML omitted
socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 8888});
```

But on Heroku, I obviously must substitute something else in for these values.

I can get the port from the process object on the server like so:

```
port = process.env.PORT || 8888
```

and pass that to the view.

But what do I substitute for `'localhost'`?

Comment: it's just tought... could you use the document.domain property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has now changed as of Oct 2013, heroku have added websocket support:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Use:

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
```

To enable websockets and dont forget to remove:

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

Comment: how do you set up the DNS to be configured if a custom domain is being used?

Comment: >  !    No such feature: sockets

Comment: `heroku features:enable websockets` => 
 Couldn't find that feature.

Answer (score 21):

The correct way according the [article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku) on heroku is:

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
socket = new io.Socket();
```

This ensures that io.Socket won't try to use WebSockets.

Comment: That works for me (note that the change has to be made on the server side).

Comment: The documentation source if anyone is interested: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

Comment: What if socket.io-client.cpp works only with websockets?

Answer (score 14):

I was able to get Socket.IO v0.8 to work on Heroku Cedar by doing the following:

**Within the Express app (in CoffeeScript in my case):**

```
app = express.createServer();
socket = require("socket.io")

...

io = socket.listen(app);
io.configure () ->
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"])
  io.set("polling duration", 10)

io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) ->
  socket.on('myaction', (data) ->
    ...
    socket.emit('result', {myData: data})

### The port setting is needed by Heroku or your app won't start
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

**And within the front-facing Javascript of your application:**

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
function sendSocketRequest() {
  socket.emit('myaction', $("#some_field").val());
}

socket.on('result', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

---

Helpful links:

- [Heroku Node help](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)
- [Heroku Socket.IO help](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)

Comment: great answer! esp. eliminate host:port duplication

Answer (score 7):

After trying every combination under the sun I finally just left it blank. Lo and behold that works perfectly. You don't even need the port.

```
socket = new io.Socket();
```

Comment: This answer is depricated since api has changed in 0.7 version

Comment: This does not work for me with socket.io 0.8.6 on Cedar stack.

Comment: Perfect answer for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem on heroku. I was able to make it work using the hostname "myapp.herokuapp.com" (or simply window.location.hostname, to work both local and in production) and setting the port to 80. I'm using SocketIO 0.6.0.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me in conjunction with adding the io.configure

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just put your actual hostname?

Comment: You know funnily enough I hadn't tried that! It doesn't seem to work though. I tried un-prefixed and 'http://' versions.

Answer (score 0):

`2011-06-25T21:41:31+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H13 (Connection closed without response) -> GET appxxxx.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/4fd434d5caad5028b1af690599f4ca8e dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=`

Does this maybe mean the heroku router infront of the app is not configured to handle web socket traffic?

**[update]**
It would appear as of 6/22/2011 the answer is yes... heroku does not support socket.io  see this post: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/22/the_new_heroku_2_node_js_new_http_routing_capabilities/

Comment: Mine still seems to work: http://radiant-wind-527.herokuapp.com/. But yeah it appears that in that article they are saying that websockets wont work.

Comment: Your app is falling back to XHR polling... in chrome console i see: `WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
`

Comment: it might also be a difference in 0.6 and 0.7 of socket.io

Comment: Have anybody successfully run  0.7 socketio on heroku?