# Node.js on Heroku with 2 ports

Tags: node.js, heroku, port

I'm trying to push a node.js app to heroku.

The app has a http server listening on one port (process.env.PORT) but I also want a web socket using another port. Is this possible in heroku? I am using ws.js to do the sockets.

On my local machine I can obviously use 3000 for one port and 8080 for the other, but I can't see how to define a second port that heroku will be happy to let me use.

thanks

matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Heroku they don't yet support WebSockets: see [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js). According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223867/can-i-set-up-socket-io-chat-on-heroku) you can use socket.io (< v0.7) to do realtime stuff, but you can't use WebSockets, it'll fall back to XHR polling.

Comment: **Heroku does now support websockets, as of 2013:** https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets

Answer (score 2):

**Heroku now supports websockets**, as of 2013. For implementation have a look at the following article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets